# grep / parse text

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I need to parse drug names from Medline abstracts. I was hoping to do this by getting outputs from `grep -wf` and `grep -owf` then using paste, but the outputs do not correspond, because `grep -owf` creates an output for each match, even if it is in the same line.

**Pattern file:**

```
DrugA
DrugB
DrugC
DrugD
```

**File to parse:**

```
In our study, DrugA and DrugB were found to be effective.  DrugA was more effective than DrugB.
In our study, DrugC was found to be effective
In our study, DrugX was found to be effective
```

**Desired output:**

```
DrugA    In our study, DrugA and DrugB were found to be effective. DrugA was more effective.
DrugB    In our study, DrugA and DrugB were found to be effective. DrugA was more effective.
DrugC    In our study, DrugC was found to be effective
```

Comment: Maybe you just need to drop the `-o`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not strictly `grep` alone, but this does the trick:

```
while IFS= read -r pattern; do
    grep "$pattern" input | awk -v drug="$pattern" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} { print drug,$0}'
done < "patterns"
```

Comment: See [this] (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 4):

An `awk` way perhaps?

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        a[$0] = 1
        n = length($0)
        w = n > w ? n : w
        next
    }
    {
        for (i in a)
            if ($0 ~ i)
                printf "%-* s %s\n", w, i, $0
    } 
' pattern_file.txt data_file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

A `sed` solution:

```
sed 's|.*|/&/{h;s/^/&\\t/p;g}|' pattern_file | sed -nf - input
```